# PHP Past time validation

Tags: php

I have a problem here validating the time of my $input on PHP.
My input has a value of

> yy-mm-dd hh:mm PM/AM

If the selected date is past or today it will got an error. How can I do that?

any help is a gratitude. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think `yy-mm-dd` is a valid date format.

Comment: Have you attempted this yourself? This problem is trivial to solve with even the slightest amount of basic searching. SO is _not_ here as a "code this for me" resource.

Comment: Have you try something ? Take a look at strtotime function

Comment: @Rocket I just tried the sample string `03-10-10 10:12 PM`, and `strtotime()` gave me an epoch (although not necessarily the correct one).

Comment: @JamWaffles: `date('r', strtotime('03-10-10 10:12 PM'))` says `Fri, 10 Oct 2003 22:12:00 +0000`. :-)

Comment: `date("c",strtotime("03-10-10 10:12 PM"))` is `"2003-10-10T22:12:00+02:00"` here, my `strtotime` version has no problems with the format. One could always use `DateTIme::createFromFormat()` to be on the safe side though.

Answer (score 5):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is your friend.

```
$input = '2012-06-07 01:23 PM';
if(strtotime($input) < time()){
    echo "error";
}
```

Comment: @Wrikken: I'm a bit dyslexic :-P

Comment: "past or today"... so `<= floor(time() / 86400 + 1) * 86400`?

Answer (score 3):

You said today, so I assume you don't mean the current time, but the current date?

```
<?php
$input = strtotime( '2012-06-07 01:23 PM' );

if ( date( 'Y-m-d', $input ) == date( 'Y-m-d' ) || $input > time() ) {
    echo 'ERROR';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$today = strtotime($todays_date);
$expiration_date = strtotime($input); 
if ($expiration_date > $today) {
 #Your code to be executed goes in here 
}
```

OR use [DateTime](http://au.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
$d1 = new DateTime("now");
$d2 = new DateTime($input);
#Use PHP's relational operators to compare the two.
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can check this using:

```
$input_date_time = strtotime( 'your input date here' );
$input_date = strtotime(date( 'Y-m-d', $input_date_time ));
$current_date = strtotime(date( 'Y-m-d',time()));

if ($input_date_time < time () || $input_date == $current_date) {
       echo "error here";
}
```

You can also use jQuery date time picker. If you are using jQuery date time picker, there is option to prevent selecting date before the current date or the date you want.

Hope this helps